# How to list users logged via remote desktop(xrdp) and ssh on Ubuntu

Tags: linux, logging, xrdp

I'm using some shared Ubuntu machine and using the `who, w, last` commands doesn't print any users just my own user. Issuing reboot print a list of users logged in via xrdp.

Is there a command that can show me the full list of logged in users on a Ubuntu system?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: xrdp sessions are not tracked with utmp/wtmp files. This repository provided some useful scripts: https://github.com/evanlinde/xrdp-who